How to wait for USB drive indefinite
I would like to use external USB flash drive to store encryption key.
Whenever the drive is attached during boot - it should decrypt Luks container and continue boot
If there is not USB drive with label KEY during boot - it should wait indefinitely (with reboot, retry, or simply wait).
I would like to make it systemd way, I already have /init script that actively tries to mount drive in endless loop, but I would like to make it more robust and systemd native.
I've tried creating mount unit:
[Unit]
Description=Mount USB Drive
Requires=dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-KEY.device
After=dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-KEY.device


[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-label/KEY
Where=/mnt/usb
Type=auto
Options=defaults
DirectoryMode=0755
TimeoutSec=0 and 100000d - the same result

[Install]
WantedBy=initrd-fs.target

it waits for default 90 seconds, and then report:
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System …eck on /dev/disk/by-label/KEY.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/usb.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.

But continues to boot, neither
JobTimeoutSec=1min
JobTimeoutAction=reboot-force

nor FailureAction=reboot-force worked.
Ideally I would like to peacefully wait for USB drive with the KEY label and then continue to boot, second best option - reboot when it was timeouted.

It's probably not (just) the mount unit that timed out, but the device unit it pulls.

Indeed, I've created:
[Unit]
Description=Wait for USB Drive with label KEY
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=local-fs-pre.target
Wants=local-fs-pre.target
FailureAction=soft-reboot-force
JobTimeoutSec=infinity
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs-pre.target
and it worked perfectly.

Created file dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-KEY.device and it is working as expected:
[Unit]
Description=Wait for USB Drive with label KEY
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=local-fs-pre.target
Wants=local-fs-pre.target
FailureAction=soft-reboot-force
JobTimeoutSec=infinity
JobTimeoutAction=soft-reboot-force

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs-pre.target


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
